# Castle Windsor XML configuration for WCF proxy using WCF Integration Facility

Tags: xml, configuration, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Currently, we use programming registration of WCF proxies in Windsor container using WCF Integration Facility. For example:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<CalculatorSoap>()
      .Named("calculatorSoap")
      .LifeStyle.Transient
      .ActAs(new DefaultClientModel
      {
        Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("CalculatorSoap").LogMessages()
      }
      )
      );
```

Is there any way to do the same via Windsor XML configuration file. I can't find any sample of this on google.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to put that in .config? Code is the recommended way

Comment: Because we want to change an implementation based on environment: in-memory implementation for dev env and WCF proxy for production env. IMHO, config is the most appropriate way for this. Currently, we use a workaround - custom WindsorInstaller that does if-else logic.

Comment: I think `IWindsorInstaller` approach is better. Move environment name to .config, not the components.

Comment: But we still have to implement kind of if-else logic in custom IWindsorInstaller. Is WCF Integration Facility via config possible at all?

Comment: No, have two installers, and use one of them. You can compile it conditionally:  `#if DEBUG` ...

AFAIK WCF Facility does not provide support for custom config, only WCF's own config section.

Comment: Ok, it can be a solution. Thank you. May be you can put is as answer to allow voting.

Comment: Just curious, does the WCF Facility deal with faulted endpoints in any way to ensure that the caller always has a valid service?
Im wondering, if the service is registered as a singleton, how one would 'release' a faulted instance being that the SingletonReleasePolicy only releases on disposal of the container, and not during a call to Release().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Castle  WCF Integration Facility repository (http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.Wcf) now contains sample of WCF client registration from Windsor configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<configuration>
<facilities>
    <facility id='wcf' 
              type='Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfFacility,
                    Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration' />
</facilities>

<components>
    <component id='calculatorSoap'
               type='Demo.CalculatorSoap, Demo.UnitTests'
               wcfEndpointConfiguration='CalculatorSoap'>
    </component>
</components>
</configuration>
```

That is what I was looking for.
Thank you for your help.

**Note:** pay attention on lifestyle. In common case, WCF proxy must have transient lifestyle to be closed on object release. While default Windsor lifestyle is singleton, in this case WCF proxy will be closed on container disposal.

Regards, Andrej

Answer (score 1):

Using `IWindsorInstaller` and doing the registration through code is the recommended way. Config is for configuration (and legacy scenarios).

I'd create two installers for this and based on compilation flag use one or the other;

```
var installer = 
#if DEBUG
new TestingServiceInstaller();
#elseif
new ProductionServiceInstaller();
#endif

container.Install(installer);
```